# Guide for PHP Sessions and Cookie usage for better security

Tags: php, ajax, session, cookies

I am working on user login/registration feature in php. And I want to protect from Session HiJacking and CSRF attacks. There are some confusions in my head and looking for answer to clarify those:

**Details**

**Registration**: The form data is validated on client side with jQuery and then converted into a json object and sent via ajax call. And the data is also validated on server side and then user is registered. Once the user is registered, session token is created using `random_bytes();` (PHP 7) function and `LoggedIn` is set to true.

```
$_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
$_SESSION['Token'] = random_bytes(32);
```

I know, I need to check for valid session on top of each private(member_area) pages. But I don't understand the purpose. Here are the question which arises in my mind:

1. Should I send session token as hidden field and validate with each request?
2. Do I need to setup cookie?
3. How can I use session token with cookie to make it more secure?
4. How can I make sure that the ajax request is valid on server side? Do I need to generate session token for visitors as well?
5. I want to keep-alive session for a week so do I need to save session token in database?

Answer (score 0):

### for csrf protection:

1. When generating the login html, insert a hidden field with some token that is generated per login request. The token has a limit life spend.
2. When the user submits his login you need to check the token. see if it is still valid (i.e not expired).
3. if it is not valid throw an error. if it is valid continue to check the credentials.

### For general purpose session authentication:

4. When a user logs in - generate a token. save it to some kind of persistence layer (database? file? memcache?). Give it an expiration date and assign it to the user that was just logged in.
5. Send the token to the user as cookie.
6. On every request - check the if the request has a cookie with a login token. If it does - check the database for that token. I*f it is expired then delete it and go back to step 1*

**About AJAX**:
don't worry about it :) theres nothing special about ajax calls. If a valid cookie is set the the above process will handle it and the user will be loaded correctly.

**About "keep-alive":**
The session will keep alive for as long as you set the expiration date in step 4